# Sublime Text URL handler for ubuntu

Tags: sublimetext2

How can I make sublime text 2 respond to `txmt` url scheme in ubuntu? This has been possible in OSX through [subl-handler](https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler) and in Windows through [SublimeProtocol](https://bitbucket.org/sublimator/sublimeprotocol/overview).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I asked me the same question today, seeing the txmt protocol with "better_errors" gem for Rails.

I search a long time but found nothing, so I tried to make it by myself.

I write an [article and my blog](http://blog.byscripts.info/2013/02/txmt-protocol-and-sublime-text-2-english.html), but I copy it here, for "future-proofness" :

## Step 1

Create the file `/usr/share/applications/sublime-handler.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime Text 2 URL Handler
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Handle URL Scheme txmt://
Exec=/home/<your_user>/bin/sublime-handler %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/txmt;
Icon=sublime-text-2
Categories=TextEditor;Development;Utility;
Name[en_US]=Sublime Text 2 URL Handler
```

## Step 2: Update the MIME-types database

```
$ sudo update-desktop-database
```

## Step 3: Create the ~/bin/sublime-handler file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

request=${1:23}               # Delete the first 23 characters
request=${request//%2F//}     # Replace %2F with /
request=${request/&line=/:}   # Replace &line= with :
request=${request/&column=/:} # Replace &column= with :
sublime-text-2 $request       # Launch ST2
```

Then make it executable : `$ chmod +x ~/bin/sublime-handler`

## Step 4: Test a txmt:// file

If that dosen't work, say me, I'll try to help you.

Comment: from Chrome or from console(xdg-open txmt://open?url=file://%2Fhome%2Fguda%2Fclub50plus%2Fapp%2Fadmin%2Fdashboard.rb&line=26) I aways get a new browser window opened. Any ideas why?

Comment: Needs an additional step:

`xdg-mime default sublime-handler.desktop x-scheme-handler/subl`

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer, because I don't have enough reputation for a comment.

For Ubuntu 14.04, Sublime Text 3, the instructions above work. Thank you so much, @ByScripts!

In Step 3, replace:

```
sublime-text-2 $request # Launch ST2
```

with:

```
subl $request # Launch ST3
```

... and don't forget to add your own username in Step 1:

```
Exec=/home/<your_user>/bin/sublime-handler %u
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but I would like to add to the accepted answer, that you'll need to also configure your browser to open txmt files with the new `~/bin/sublime-handler`

I saved my handler in `/usr/bin`, which also works btw.

To configure Firefox:

1. go to Edit > Preferences > Applications or enter the following into the URI field
   `about:preferences#applications`
2. search for `txmt`
3. on the `txmt` entry click on the action field and browse for your sublime-handler file